# Series Expansions in Mathematica

Tags: bugs, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 5.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.1**

---

Define variable `z` with the following assumptions

```
$Assumptions = 0 < z < 1
```

I put in the following two codes in Mathematica

```
t1 = Simplify[Series[ArcTanh[(1 - Sqrt[z])^2], {z, 0, 3}]]

t2 = Simplify[Series[ArcTanh[(1 - Sqrt[z])^2] // TrigToExp, {z, 0, 3}]]
```

The codes are identical to each other except for the extra `TrigToExp`. Yet, the outputs are completely different

$$t_1 = -\frac{\log (z)}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{z}}{4}+\frac{z}{16}+\frac{5
   z^{3/2}}{48}+\frac{z^2}{16}+\frac{z^{5/2}}{40}+O\left(z^{7/2}\right) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\\
t_2 = -\frac{\log (z)}{4}-\frac{\sqrt{z}}{4}+\frac{z}{16}+\frac{5 z^{3/2}}{48}+\frac{9 z^2}{128}+\frac{9
   z^{5/2}}{320}+\frac{z^3}{768}+O\left(z^{7/2}\right)
$$

Why are the two results different and which result should I trust?

Comment: Just add a few more terms `Series[... {z,0,7}]` you will see that the two Series will diverge only for the higher order terms. The first expression without `TrigToExp` seems to converge faster to the correct values.

Comment: You can wrap Assuming around those series Assuming[0 < z < 1, t1 = Simplify[Series[ArcTanh[(1 - Sqrt[z])^2], {z, 0, 3}]]] instead of setting a global variable like $Assumptions.

Comment: @grbl - if you write that up i'll choose it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: There is indeed a problem with the direct (as opposed to `TrigToExp`'ed) version. Looking into it.

Answer (score 5):

The which one can you trust, can be answered by plotting the error,

$$\left |\tanh ^{-1}\left(\left(1-\sqrt{z}\right)^2\right)-\text{t1}  \right | \text{ and } \left |\tanh ^{-1}\left(\left(1-\sqrt{z}\right)^2\right)-\text{t2}  \right |$$

```
t1 = Simplify[Series[ArcTanh[(1 - Sqrt[z])^2], {z, 0, 3}]] //Normal;

t2 = Simplify[Series[ArcTanh[(1 - Sqrt[z])^2] // TrigToExp, {z, 0, 3}]] //Normal;

Plot[{Abs[ArcTanh[(1 - Sqrt[z])^2] - t1], 
  Abs[ArcTanh[(1 - Sqrt[z])^2] - t2]}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}, PlotLabels -> {"f(z)-t1", "f(z)-t2"}]
```

[image]

Looks like t2 would be my choice for  0 < z < 1 / 2 and t1 for the rest.

Comment: You are welcome.