# Series expansion of Lerch transcendent still buggy?

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

[This series expansion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132687/another-series-expansions-in-mathematica) of a [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) seems fixed in V12. However, the following still fails: From the definition of a Lerch transcendent,

```
Assuming[z > 0, Sum[(-1)^k/(z + k), {k, 0, ∞}]]
(*    LerchPhi[-1, 1, z]    *)
```

we expect the series-expansion around $z=0$ to give a dominant term of $1/z$ (i.e., the $k=0$ term), but instead it gives the wholly nonsensical

```
Series[LerchPhi[-1, 1, z], {z, 0, 2}]
(*     -Log[2] + π^2/12*z - 3/4*Zeta[3]*z^2 + O[z]^3    *)

Plot[{LerchPhi[-1, 1, z], -Log[2] + π^2/12*z - 3/4*Zeta[3]*z^2}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

## Update

As J.M. points out, the series expansion of `LerchPhi` merely omits the singular term, so the given series expansion isn't wholly nonsensical:

```
Plot[{LerchPhi[-1, 1, z] - 1/z, -Log[2] + π^2/12*z - 3/4*Zeta[3]*z^2}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I find this behavior very confusing: the option `IncludeSingularTerm` seems to default to `True` when plotting, and defaul to `False` when series-expanding. Further,

```
LerchPhi[-1, 1, z, IncludeSingularTerm -> False]
```

does not exclude the singular term.

A bug?

Comment: By default, `LerchPhi[]` has the setting `IncludeSingularTerm -> False`, so the `1/z` term is tacitly excluded for `z == 0`.